# Is there a way of getting a permanent access token from Google service account?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on an iOS app (using Swift) that sends push notifications between two users when any of them sends a message to the other (and when other events happen as well). For that, I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging and this is the swift function that actually sends the notification:

```
        let accessToken  = "xxxx"
        
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/\( K.FCMessaging.projectId)/messages:send"
        
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        
        let paramString: [String : Any] = ["message": [
            "apns" : ["payload" : ["aps": ["alert": ["title": title, "body": body], "sound": "default"] as [String : Any], OrderModel.CodingKeys.orderId.rawValue: order.orderId!, OrderModel.CodingKeys.senderId.rawValue: order.senderId] as [String : Any]],
            "token" : receiverToken] as [String : Any]
        ]
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
        task.resume()
```

The access token is obtained by running this python code locally on the Mac:

```
import argparse
import json
import requests
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account


PROJECT_ID = 'xxxx'
BASE_URL = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com'
FCM_ENDPOINT = 'v1/projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/messages:send'
FCM_URL = BASE_URL + '/' + FCM_ENDPOINT
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging']

def access_token():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/Users/...-firebase-xxxx.json', scopes=SCOPES)
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(request)
    return credentials.token
```

Now everything works fine (i.e. the notifications get sent and received) when I copy the access token into the swift function, but it expires after one hour and I have to run the code again and copy the access token again.
Since I don't have a server to automatically run the python function on, it seems like I'm missing something.
Can you please tell me how to get a permanent access token for the app or the right way of sending push notifications between two devices in iOS?

Comment: You should use a server. You can use a Google cloud run service or Google cloud function. You can create a key file for your Google service account and embed that in your app and have your app use it to obtain an access token but that Keyfile can be obtained from your app and used.

Comment: You can also trigger the cloud function from the Firestore update, so that your app doesn't need to do anything to send the notification other than update the Firestore

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you mean saving the token found in a file in the cloud and have the app access it?

Comment: Also, is there a way of achieving it without using Google cloud functions or cloud run service?

Comment: It isn't secure to have the mobile app call the FCM endpoint directly. You can use other cloud services like AWS or Azure but the advantage of using a Google's cloud environment is that the service has a Google identity itself, so it can just call the FCM endpoint without you needing to do anything other than authorise the service's account to do so.

Comment: The problem is that all these services require a non-prepaid credit card, which is not available in my country. That's why I was stuck. I guess I just have to settle with what is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: No, not with FCM v1.

Since Google transitioned to FCM v1, they now mandate the use of OAuth2, unlike FCM (legacy). OAuth2 functions by generating temporary tokens, which serve as a preventive measure against various attacks, such as man-in-the-middle attacks. Consequently, the use of a permanent code is unfortunately not possible.

As mentioned in the comments, the most straightforward approach in my opinion is to leverage Google Cloud Functions. This approach minimizes the workload for your local app. However, it’s unfortunate that you don’t have access in your country.

Comment: Thanks for the concise and accurate answer. I was finally able to use a python script on my computer that automatically gets executed every hour (if the computer is turned on). That python script gets a new access code each time and saves it in the database.

Comment: Glad you could work it out. If you think my answer answers your (and maybe other's) question, I would appreciate if you could accept it.